# How does pipe behave in a cron job script?

Tags: bash, cron, pipe, cat

I have some data in some files and I am piping the data to a filter using `cat`.

```
cat /home/user/data1.bin /home/user/data2.bin |
          /home/user/bin/datafilter -f /home/user/output.txt
```

When I run this on the command line it works as expected. When I put it in a bash script, I can run that script from the command line.

However when I run this script with `cron`, I get no output, i.e. output.txt is NOT produced.

I fully understand that `cron` requires all the environments and paths to be created and I do this. This is the only part of the script that is not working.

Comment: Do you have the line break in your cron file? Without the line break, it should work just fine